# Issue with file downloading using ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: ios, xcode, asihttprequest

I am downloading an audio file from server.I am using `ASINetworkQueue`,`ASIHTTPRequest`.But when I gave the destination path with extension ".`mp3`",It's not getting downloading but it's entering into

`[networkQueue setRequestDidFinishSelector:@selector(dataDownloadCompleted:)];`

When I tested with the extension ".caf" its perfectly working.Is there any way to achieve with extension ".mp3"
Any help will be appreciable

Comment: How about using `NSURLConnection`?

Comment: is request URL ends with .mp3 extension?

Comment: so it will ends with .caf?

Comment: As I know the file can't accept the .mp3 extension

Comment: ASIHTTPRequest is discontinued. The last update was over 2 years ago. Don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

`ASIHTTPRequest` has been discontinued.

The last update is over 2 years old.

You shouldn't be using it at all.

If you must use a networking framework then take a look at `AFNetworking`.

Or do it yourself using `NSURLRequest` and `NSURLConnection`.

Comment: Thank you for your information :).In my project I am already using ASIHTTPRequest,Is there any way to achieve my goal using ASIHTTPRequest